# Geb JUnit4 autogenerated tests

Tags: testing, groovy, junit4, geb

Is it possible to generate tests and run them?

I have for e.g. a list of URLs that I would like to check if they are pointing to a 404 page and some other tests. I don't want to create for each link a seperated test. That would be a lot of work.

If it's not possible, is it possible to point from a test to another one and if the another one fails that the first test just continues?

For my testing I'm using Groovy with Gebish, Gradle and JUnit4.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for are [parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) tests, not generated tests. If I understand you correctly, you want to run the *same* test for lots of different 'things'.

In a parameterized test, you do that by declaring a static method which returns the data and then telling JUnit to use the `Parameterized` runner to run the test. Each test class is then instantiated with an argument as the test data, which the test method can have access to.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }  
           });
    }

    private int fInput;
    private int fExpected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        fInput= input;
        fExpected= expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
    }
}
```

An alternative approach would be [theories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Theories). With a theory you embed the test data in the test class as different static fields annotated with `@Datapoint` and each test method is called repeatedly for each datapoint, with the specific data point being passed as an argument. Again, you have a special runner to make it happen...

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class UserTest {
    @DataPoint
    public static String GOOD_USERNAME = "optimus";
    @DataPoint
    public static String USERNAME_WITH_SLASH = "optimus/prime";

    @Theory
    public void filenameIncludesUsername(String username) {
        assumeThat(username, not(containsString("/")));
        assertThat(new User(username).configFileName(), containsString(username));
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also make your life a whole lot easier and use [Spock](https://github.com/spockframework/spock) and [its support for test parameterization](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html).